# chartJs with MySQL and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, mysqli

I'm trying to make a line chat with chartJs.

I want to push MySQL data to chartJs using php.

MySQL table

```
id  | page_views | visitors | month |
------------------------------------| 
1   |   200      |   20     | Jan   |
2   |   100      |   10     | Feb   |
3   |   500      |   30     | March |
------------------------------------|
```

chartJs

```
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
        var lineChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
                }
            ]

        }

    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    }
```

I want to apply MySQL loop for this.

Can anyone give me a simple example how to do this?

Comment: Did it work with getting the data through ajax with json?

Comment: @st2erw2od Yes it did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChartJS takes data in JSON format.

You can get JSON data with AJAX.

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://yourdomain.com/yourfile.php',
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (results){
```

In the calling PHP file you can program your logic and database access. You then can echo the data with `json_encode` to output the array in JSON format.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dataArray);
```

You then can add the data to the chart like this:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(jsonData);
```

Comment: In addition you can use [PHPChartJS](https://github.com/halfpastfouram/PHPChartJS) on the server side.